# Editing a stored keyboard macro and storing the edited version

Tags: keyboard-macros

In my ~/.emacs, there are several keyboard macros stored. They appear as `(fset 'dhteu-macro-name ...` entries. BTW, `dhteu` is just a random alphabet combination prefixed to avoid collision with any existing commands.

I can `C-x C-k e M-x` supply a macro name and a buffer opens allowing me to edit the macro. I can edit it and save it with `C-c C-c`. Now if I `C-x C-k e M-x` same macro name, I see the modified version. I tried executing the modified macro on a buffer. The madified macro executes successfully.

After all this, I naturally, want to store the macro. So, I visit `~/.emacs` and `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. I expect the name of the macro I just edited to be available at this prompt. It isn't.

Entering the entire name produces a no match error.

I tried `C-x C-k n` to give it another name. That produces a `No keyboard macro defined` error.

So, the question is: How do I edit a stored keyboard macro and save it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in Emacs.  When saving the macro, Emacs fails to add the `kmacro` property, so that when you start a new session, Emacs doesn't remember that `dhteu-macro-name` is actually a keyboard macro.

The hack below should workaround the problem.

```
(defun my-kmacro-hack (&rest _)
  (interactive
   (list (intern (completing-read
                  "Insert kbd macro (name): "
                  obarray
                  (lambda (elt)
                    (and (fboundp elt)
                         (or (stringp (symbol-function elt))
                             (vectorp (symbol-function elt))
                             (kmacro-extract-lambda (symbol-function elt)))))
                  t))
         current-prefix-arg))
  nil)
(advice-add 'insert-kbd-macro :before #'my-kmacro-hack)
```

I installed a cleaner fix which will into Emacs's `master` branch (i.e. for Emacs-27).

Comment: I am a complete newbie. But I think there is a gap between what I have written and your reply. So, this comment. I can very well see all the stored (in ~/.emacs) macros. I can very well edit `C-x C-k e M-x name` any of them and save (`C-c C-c` in the macro editor) it for the session. But when I try to `insert-kbd-macro` it does not recognize this macro. If I record a new macro, there is no problem. Lastly, when do we expect to see Emacs27 in Kubuntu? :)

Comment: When you create a macro (with `C-x C-k n`), the *name* is marked to remember that it's a keyboard macro.  But when you `C-x C-k n` that detail is not written, so when you restart Emacs, the command is defined but the name is not marked as a keyboard macro (and Emacs doesn't recognize the actual definition as a keyboard macro either).  My patch makes Emacs recognize the definition instead of checking if the name is marked as a keyboard macro.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand it better now. But if such is the case with emacs as it stands now, what is the alternative? I have been a vim user for the past several years and I am so used to writing quick keyboard macros, editing them, etc. without any trouble. I am planning to migrate to emacs and this may prove to be a big hurdle. Are there any packages/ workarounds that you may suggest?

Comment: I put some sample code you can use in your `~/.emacs` which should work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. But in my case, it produced a Wrong number of arguments error. The error includes everything upto the advice line. Also, do you think elmacro is a solution?

Comment: I fixed the arglist, which was lacking the actual (ignored) argument.  You can try again.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That works perfectly. Can I remove that bit from my ~/.emacs when Emacs-27 is installed on my computer? I am running Kubuntu 17.10

Comment: Yes, it should be both useless and harmless in Emacs-27 and it could become harmful in the future, so better remove it once you get there.